# Do can I convert this query syntax linq expression to method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I've written this code to join two tables together from sql server, now I want to write this as in method syntax. How can I rewrite this code?

```
LinqToLoginDataContext lnqdore = new LinqToLoginDataContext();
var f = (from k in lnqdore.Table_Years
         join h in lnqdore.Table_Dores on k.Id equals h.FK_Year
         where h.Id == (int)dataviewDore.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value
         select k).Single();
```

Comment: i want change this sintax only for learning lambda sintax

Comment: If you want to learn something, then try it yourself first. Read msdn or articles about lambda syntax. Solving this by SO users doesn't look like part of your learning process

Comment: FYI ReSharper has a refactoring that changes query syntax to lambda syntax.

Comment: Just another "do-this-for-me" type of question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var f = lnqdore.Table_Years
    .Join(lnqdore.Table_Dores, k => k.ID, h => h.FK_Year, (k, h) => new { k, h })
    .Where(res => res.h.ID == (int)dataviewDore.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value)
    .Select(res => res.k)
    .Single();
```

Comment: Please do not support this type of questions. Thank you!

Comment: why do not support this type of questions?

Comment: @user3116296 He means that, you can read one of many articles about LINQ method syntax with the help of lambda expressions. And after reading that, you will have better knowledge about it and you will solve your problem for your own.